# Can I show a powerpoint document inside an iframe or something on a page?

Tags: powerpoint

I am using SP2013. I have a powerpoint document. I would like to show this powerpoint show inside my site on page. So I can see also the masterpage with the navigation on the left and in the header. Is this possible within an iframe webpart or something else?

Comment: You would need the PowerPoint viewer, but other than that just follow this guide http://blogs.technet.com/b/ptsblog/archive/2011/02/01/embedding-a-powerpoint-deck-on-sharepoint-2010.aspx (yepp #1 result when googling "Powerpoint viewer sharepoint")

Comment: How can I use the PowerPoint viewer? Is it included in SharePoint 2013 Standard?

Comment: I dont have office web apps.

Comment: Well that is what you need to display ppt files in the browser

Comment: No other way to embed the powerpoint slide show in some page?

Comment: @KHA Upload to SlideShare and embed from there would solve the problem at hand, but maybe you don't want to share with the rest of the world?

Comment: thats a good workaround..